# How to make Input Field in antd autogrow based on length of value?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to use an input field from Ant design system that grows in width automatically upto a certain limit to keep the all the chararters of the input field in view all the time.
Currently AntD input field has only fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following example using useState, you can change the default width value of the input field as per your requirement. Once input width value reaches 100 it will stop growing (you can change the value).

```
import React from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Input } from 'antd';

const Demo = () => {
  const [inputwidth, setinputWidth] = useState(50);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    let length = e.target.value.length;
    if (length === 0) {
      setinputWidth(50);
    }
    if (inputwidth <= 100) {
       setinputWidth(50 + e.target.value.length * 5);
    }
  };

  return <Input onChange={onChange} style={{ width: inputwidth }} />;
};
export default Demo
```

Comment: Here have you assumed that 1 character in the input box is of width 5px?

Comment: @PiyushChauhan Yes, this is just a example, you can change the values as per your requirements. :)